# Creating JPA Entity from base class

Tags: java, jpa

I have a List of registries coming into my application via a Queue, I have a Registry class from a common library

```
public class Registry {

   private String rowId;
   private String code;
   private String status;
}
```

and I want to persist this registry entity in a relational db table (where rowId is the primary key and I also need to add a sequence id).  So I created a jpa entity that extends Registry

```
@Entity
public class RegistryEntity extends Registry {
   @Id
   private String rowId;
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Integer sequenceId;
}

public interface RegistryRespository extends JpaRepository<RegistryEntity, String> {}
```

is there an elegant way (without having to instantiate each RegistryEntity) to transform `List<Registry>` to `List<RegistryEntity>` so I can do the following

```
List<Registry> registries = getFromQueue();

registryRespository.saveAll(RegistryEntityList)
```

Comment: One way or another you will have to loop over the List<Registry> and create RegistryEntity objects. Are you aware you defined rowId twice  ? My advice is to not let RegistryEntity extend Registry as RegistryEntity is part of your internal persistency layer and Registry is part of the public contract. I would prefer to keep these 2 separated.

Comment: There are multiple mapping mechanisms are available to map between DTO object and entity but I would recommend use `mapstruct` which is convenient to use here. look at https://mapstruct.org/ https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

Comment: You can use ModelMapper also

Answer (score 0):

Spring providing API
`BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destinate, ignore props)`
just pass the references which fit your criteria. and you will be done with as per expected result.

Comment: Thanks I probably will use List<Registry> and create RegistryEntity objects.  I had the rowId in `RegistryEntity` because of the @id annotation.  What's the proper way to add jpa annotations to fields in a jpa entity that are defined in the super class